# htaccess check length of a part of a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I want apache to skip certain rewrites in case part of a request is shorter than 255 characters (has to do with caching and the 255 character filename limit in linux).

I've written this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm_campaign" 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm_medium" 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\/)([^\/\n]{0,255})$ 
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
```

And I tested the regex against the url (`q=path/to/page?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_medium=xxx`) and it matches but the query_string variable seems to have a different content because the 2 rules after this still get executed. The part that should match is in this case `page?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_medium=xxx` (and everything after this) If this is shorter than 255 characters the next 2 rewrite rules can be skipped.

I'm using Drupal 6 btw.

Comment: Your rules ale correct, the problem is in something else. I see some confusion in your statements... please note, the content of apache variables available in `mod_rewrite` is as follows: when accessed URL is `http://www.example.com/path/file.ext?var=1&var2=2`... the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/path/file.ext`, `%{QUERY_STRING}` is `var=1&var2=2`... so in your example, `page?` is NOT part of the variable... not sure, if it makes any difference nor solves your problem

Comment: This was indeed key to the problem, I should have used: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\/)([^\/\n]{0,255})$ (the underscore is a replacement for the questionmark )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part before the ? is not in %{QUERY_STRING} (contrary to $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] in PHP in this case, hence the confusion), adding %{REQUEST_URI} to the RewriteCond solved the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm_campaign" 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%_{QUERY_STRING} "utm_medium" 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\/)([^\/\n]{0,255})$ 
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
```

Not sure how to give @Kamil Šrot credit for this solution since the answer is in a comment?

Comment: If you want to test both the uri and the query_string, then you can probably just use THE_REQUEST.

Comment: THE_REQUEST contains the full request line, this will cause other problems with the regex in this case. Did not know about this variable and might be usefull in other cases so thanks for commenting anyway.

Comment: @Zeki using `THE_REQUEST` is last option and shouldn't be used if not absolutely necessary. This variable contains raw request before normalization and any processing and dealing with it directly creates other problems - security, complexity of rules, ...